# Merging ViewFlipper with ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, viewflipper

What I'm trying to do is to have horizontal ViewFlipper and Listview, both with custom ArrayAdapters, inside LinearLayout which would be vertically scrollable on whole screen.

1) Tried adding ViewFlipper as a ListView header but then I can't use GestureListener since ArrayAdapter takes control over it like it's ListView item.

2) Tried putting them together inside LinearLayout but ViewFlipper's position is fixed and ListView is scrollable inside rest of the screen.

3) Trying with [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) but it can't handle swipe gesture on it's first element (ViewFlipper), it always returns ViewFlipper's item position.

Here's the picture to clarify what I'm trying to make. Top Stories is ViewFlipper and Latest Posts is ListView. And they both scroll vertically. Ignore bottom tabs and ActionBar as they are static (nonscrollable).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your work cut out for you.

Here are two approaches:

1) Set the view flipper as the first row in the List view. Its a special case. Not as a header, but as a regular row.

2) Use a scroll view, and do not use the list view at all. You may have performance problems if your data for the list view is a large number of items.

Comment: Thanks, adding views manually surely works but I thought there was some other, more elegant solution.

Comment: What did you end up going with for this? I need the same layout, and am running into the same exact problem. I can't go with #2 because the dataset is too large. For #1, are we supposed to include a ViewFlipper in each row of our adapter, and only use it for the first element?

Comment: Maybe try the suggestion below, ViewPager. But from what you are describing you might also get some good mileage from redesigning your interface. If the flipper is important content, it doesn't make sense to take it off screen. And if its not, it doensn't make sense to make it a flipper and at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ViewPager` from the [Android Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) it does what you need

Comment: Sorry, I guess you misunderstood me, I edited question to clarify.